# Windows Server 2003 not correctly handling SSL in my application "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-server-2003

I can't quite figure out what is going wrong here. My application calls multiple different apis, all using SSL. The exception does not tell me much about where it's getting stuck, and the application works fine on multiple Windows 10 machines and one Windows 7 machine. The application was built in .Net 4, which is installed on the server.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Werkbon_naar_Appeee.Task.Get()
   at Werkbon_naar_Appeee.Main.Form2_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I don't know much about how SSL works and what could be going wrong here. Searching for a solution hasn't helped me much.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

I have manually installed all the certificates into the correct directories using MMC but when I browse to the website I still get a certificate error. I have also tried using the wizard to automatically install the certificates but to no avail. The application has continued to work without problems on other machines. What could be the reason for this issue? Is it possible that the certificate is incompatible with old operating systems?

Comment: "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"

Comment: That's right. The first answer has provided a link that should technically solve the issue, but after following the instructions word for word, the problem still persists. I have tried it multiple times, deleting the certificates and adding them manually again but it simply doesn't work.

Comment: You need `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` without check for remote certificate validity. Choose the corresponding `SslStream` constructor with custom cert validation.

Answer (score 0):

Are these self signed certificates? The error `The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure` implies there is something wrong the certificate, like it isn't from a trusted authority or has expired.

You may need to add the certificate manually to the machine calling the API.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/09/16/troubleshooting-asp-net-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure/

**Update**

Check out the answer on the page below to download the certificate using firefox

https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file

Click on the SSL certificate icon at the top / Padlock at the bottom.

Click View Certificate

Click on the Details Tab

Chose which certificate you want from the hierarchy

Click Export

**To Add the certificate to your store** use the instruction provided in the previous link.

Comment: This is not concerning a self signed certificate. I opened the api being called in a browser and it says "There is a problem with this website's security certificate". So i was able to isolate the api causing the problem, but i can't figure out how i can add this website to the list of trusted certificates, even with the link you provided. I need to get a certificate file to export, where can i find this file?

Comment: Please see my updated answer for instructions on exporting the certificate using firefox.

Comment: Yes, that does help, thank you. However, it still doesn't seem to be working. I installed the certificate in the current user as well as the local computer, and it shows up in the list like normal, but the error hasn't changed at all. I can't tell where i'm going wrong here.

Comment: so when you visit the website you no longer get a security warning?

Comment: The link I've provided explains everything you'll need to do to get this working, it could be any number of things, most like an intermediate authority issue but I advise you to read through that article properly from start to finish and follow any appropriate steps/instructions.

Comment: I have read the article multiple times, followed all the steps multiple times and it simply will not work. I've manually installed all the certificates, root and intermediate, then when that didn't work i let all of them automatically choose a directory, didn't work either. I can't even get it to work in the browser, let alone my application. I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: The certificate might be using outdated signing techniques which could explain why your browser still complains even after installing the certificates. .Net shouldn't care though. What API is this? I'd be getting in touch with the developer/company and let them know that they're certificate is broken and a security risk.if you've followed all of the steps and it still isn't working then I'm afraid I can't offer much more help, this is definitely a certificate issue which is something you don't have a lot of control over. In saying that installing the certificate should work just fine.